# I am thinking of designing an electric car and am wondering about the best way to drive the wheels

Tags: batteries, motor, automotive

I'm thinking of a light cart - barely enough room for one person and the batteries.

What do you think would give me the best battery life?

I am thinking a (brushless?) motor with the input voltage constantly set to its peek efficiency? And for the occasional torque for starting and hills, would a gearbox of some form be good?

**Edit**

I'm planing on using [this motor type](http://www.thingap.com/products/Large_Motors/construction.htm) for its design and high RPM, but since it doesn't do well on low speed and hi torque, I'm having second thoughts. Maybe stick with the "classics".

So I ask: Is it a good idea to set it to it's top battery efficient speed and regulate its torque with a gearbox? Or should I use a different motor?

Comment: Could you possibly clarify your question a little more?  It's not that clear what you're asking for here.  Are you designing an electric car?  What specific technology are you asking about?  What are you envisaging in the way of battery voltages, etc?

Comment: Why did you choose this motor, apart from its novelty? It has characteristics that may commend it for some uses. What aspects of it make it desirable in your application?

Comment: I'm panning on using it as an in wheel motor.

Comment: And an Epicyclic Gearbox for torque in it. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicyclic_gearing)

Comment: @GustavoFSx, If you can give us name and information without a link it would be great. The link will not load for me at all.

Comment: It's just a wikipedia article /Epicyclic_gearing

Comment: Have you considered collaborating with [OScar](http://www.theoscarproject.org/), the [Open Source Car](http://opensourceecology.org/wiki/Open_Source_Car) project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of a switching power supply as a electronic gearbox.  It's going to be lot lighter than a mechanical gearbox to handle the same power.  It can be varied finely and quickly, unlike the mechanical gearbox that has a small number of fixed ratios.

I would start with the right motor for the job, then design the electronics around it.  With a good motor and motor driver, you should be able to get both good low speed torque and high speed efficiency.

These are only general observations since your question is otherwise too broad to answer effectively without writing a book.

Comment: I would rather compare a switcher with the clutch pedal than with a gearbox. (Yes, I know that in the US you all have automatic transmission, and yes, the pedal would wear out quickly when pressed 100 000 times per second...)

Comment: @stevenvh: You can sortof say a switcher works by switching the clutch in and out, but that is likely to be more confusing than illuminating.  What I meant by the gearbox analogy is that a switcher can convert the Watts in to various combinations of Volts and Amps out.  A geabox converts the Watts in to a few different tradeoffs of torque and speed.  The electronics may achieve this by doing something clutch-like very fast, but that's a implementation detail, and not totally accurate either.

Comment: A clutch would behave more like a variable resistor than a power supply.  While variable or switchable resistances can certainly be used in motor control (resistor banks are, or at least used to be, used to limit start-up torque on diesel-electric locomotives), they are like a clutch (and unlike a switching supply) in that they control the output voltage/torque purely by wasting energy, rather than altering the effective impedance.

Comment: I don't know any really good mechanical analogy for a switching supply, though it could be described somewhat in analog terms.  Consider electricity as water, and an inductor as being like a very heavy water wheel.  Suppose one has a high-pressure water source and one wishes to power a device that needs less pressure.  If one puts a fast-acting valve and a water wheel between the source and the device, it will take a little while for water to start moving through the wheel and letting enough pressure reach the device.  If one closes the switch after the flow of water has increased enough...

Comment: ...the water wheel will continue to supply pressure for awhile; during that time, there will be a partial vacuum on the upstream side of it.  Low-pressure water (lower pressure than needed for the device) will be more than happy to fill that partial vacuum, if allowed to do so, and its water wheel will use its kinetic energy to increase its pressure.  Whereas a simple flow-restricting valve would have to take a gallon of water from the high-pressure side for each gallon of water the output device lets through...

Comment: ...using a fast-acting valve, water wheel, and a mechanism to let lower-pressure water into the area between the valve and the wheel, will allow more water to reach the output device than is taken from the source.